# Ajax for Javascript content not working

Tags: javascript, ajax, d3.js

when using ajax, will this code bring up javascript content?

```
 var xmlhttp;
var nocache = 0;



function further($id)
{
    xmlhttp=getXmlHttpObject();
    if (xmlhttp==null)
    {
        alert ("Browser does not support HTTP Request");
        return;
    }
    var url="further.php?Pid=" + $id;
    //url=url+"cachestopper=" + Math.random();

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=handleAjaxResponse;
    xmlhttp.open("GET",url,'&nocache = '+nocache,true);
    xmlhttp.send(null);
}

function handleAjaxResponse()
{
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4)
    {
        document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;

    }else{
        document.getElementById("main").innerHTML = "";
    }
}

function getXmlHttpObject()
{
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {
        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        return new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    if (window.ActiveXObject)
    {
        // code for IE6, IE5
        return new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    return null;
}
```

I know this works well for html and text content, but in my case, I need to produce a diagram that is generated using javascript, d3.js to be exact. Will .innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText; work for this? If not, what will I have to use instead to produce the javascript content?

Comment: Please post your full code . "xmlhttp" is a global object ? . It will not be resolved in handleAjaxResponse.

Comment: I have edited the code above to show the entire ajax.js file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A small bug in your code while opening  a XMLHttpRequest Object.

```
xmlhttp.open("GET",url,'&nocache = '+nocache,true);

It should be 
 xmlhttp.open("GET",url+'&nocache = '+nocache,true);
```

Try this http://jsfiddle.net/nubgw/7/